# Push Notification Error

Tags: iphone

I am trying to display push-notifications in my application. I have created ApId's, enabled the push-notifications and created the P12-certificates. I sent a request to the server, but the following error occurred:

> ```
> Error - An error occurred while reading Apple response for token 90241600842ee12f13378b33b03a1600200000009cff033fa037160000b00f00 - Input string was not in a correct format.
> ```

What should I do?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this question later, this error is given when you use a production certificate in the sandbox environment.